# Getting path to URI is always null?

Tags: android, file, uri, retrofit, android-gallery

So i am using retrofit to upload images to our server, and am using gallery chooser to choose the image. I am trying to get the path of the image, because uri.getPath() returns file not found exception. I have literally seen almost every stackoverflow article on this subject, and still have no answer. The following code that I have is similar to everything I have seen online, and it ALWAYS returns null, and I have no idea why. PLEASE HELP

```
        @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        try {
            android.net.Uri selectedImage = data.getData();

            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), selectedImage);
            // Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(bitmap));
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.expandedProfilePic);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            android.database.Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            if (cursor == null)
                return;

            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            // is always null
            System.out.println("FILE PATH " + filePath);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am trying to get the path of the image, because uri.getPath() returns file not found exception

Assuming that by "gallery chooser", you mean `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` or possibly `ACTION_PICK`, there is no path, because a `Uri` is not a file.

> I have literally seen almost every stackoverflow article on this subject

No, you have not. Specifically, you have not read any of the dozens that I have contributed to, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789276/android-get-real-path-by-uri-getpath/44069931?s=1|0.0000#44069931) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43916090/get-image-from-gallery-with-intent/43916508?s=2|0.0000#43916508) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43818723/unable-to-access-file-from-uri/43819665?s=3|0.0000#43819665) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43333427/getting-file-from-device-on-android-keeps-stating-file-not-found-when-trying-to/43333469?s=5|0.0000#43333469) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43297323/how-to-use-intent-to-pick-a-xml-file-and-parse-it-dynamically/43297684?s=6|0.0000#43297684) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43194470/taking-photo-video-and-attaching-to-email-in-android/43195655?s=7|0.0000#43195655) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42542572/cannot-create-a-file-using-the-uri-of-action-get-content/42542672?s=12|0.0000#42542672) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42508885/how-to-upload-selected-video-from-nougat-path-returning-null/42530653?s=13|0.0000#42530653) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42458910/how-to-get-audio-absolute-path-in-android-using-createchooser/42458987?s=15|0.0000#42458987) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42375484/android-get-the-real-path-and-file-name-from-uri/42375567?s=18|0.0000#42375567) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42181319/get-uri-from-image-in-android/42181636?s=20|0.0000#42181636) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42040301/get-the-image-name-and-path-by-selecting-it-from-gallery-for-saving/42040511?s=21|0.0000#42040511) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41900707/file-not-found-selecting-a-video-from-gallery/41900792?s=24|0.0000#41900792). And those are just from 2017.

> The following code that I have is similar to everything I have seen online

And that code will not work for most `Uri` values.

Use a `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content identified by the `Uri`. Ideally, you would just use the `InputStream`. In the case of Retrofit, while I have not tried uploading content with it, my guess is that it insists upon a file. In that case, use the `InputStream` and a `FileOutputStream` on some file that you control to make a copy of the content. Then, upload the copy, deleting it when you are done.